# Difference between year 2018 and date 2018-01-01

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table responsible for storing dates. I want to be able to input there 2018-01-01 which represents month (January) and I want to store there 2018 which represents year. Is this possible?

Comment: `2018-01-01` is January 1st, 2018, not January 2018 or January, the month. `January 2018` is a date range, not a date. So is the year 2018. What are you actually trying to do? The question doesn't make much sense the way it is now.

Comment: A typical way to deal with date ranges is to use a Calendar table, ie a table that contains one row for each date for the next eg 50 years, with extra columns for month, year, week number, fiscal period etc. This makes querying for such periods a *lot* easier. If you want to store date ranges in a table though, two date fields with the start and end date would probably be the easiest way to do so.

Comment: So you want a table with three nullable columns, namely `Year`, `Month` and `Day`? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would have to use an integer datatype for date column that store year.

```
 insert into #tbltest1 values(datepart(year, getdate() ))
```